# Where to place custom components

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2, extjs6

I'm starting a new app with `ExtJS 6`. In my traditional 4.2 folder structure I used to have my custom controls in a "core" folder.

[image]

Now In version 6, I see a new structure:

[image]

I don't know if the right thing is to add my "core" folder in "`app->view`" or in "`app->classic->view`", my logic says that it should go in the first so any control can be visible from any theme classic, modern, etc.

Comment: I'd create a package...

Comment: Sinceraly Im new to packages... how does that work. Appreciate it

Comment: http://docs.sencha.com/cmd/6.x/cmd_packages/cmd_packages.html